# MS Excel populate one column based on two other column

Tags: excel

I have two excels

### Sheet1:

```
COM_CD  COM_NAME   CLS_CD  DPT_CD  CLS_NAME
------  --------   ------  ------  --------
45210   Apple       463     55
45220   Banana      463     55
45230   Orange      463     55
45935   Grapes      463     56
45835   Mango       463     73
45135   Butter      463     73
```

### Sheet2:

```
CLS_CD  DPT_CD   CLS_NAME
------  -----    --------
463     55       Store1
463     56       Store2
463     73       Store3
```

the first sheet have unique CLS_NAME with the combination of CLS_CD and DPT_CD and based on the CLS_CD and DPT_CD I want to populate the second sheet CLS_NAME, is there any formula to do this? help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!A:C,3,0) this formula solved the problem